# KSQL unable to create a stream with a key of string and a value of Integer

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a very simple kafka producer that sends data using the following:

```
ProducerRecord producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String, Integer>(topic, symbol, value);
producer.send(producerRecord);
```

basically a key/value pair where the value is an integer.

How do I define a stream for this in ksql? I tried:

```
create stream mystream (symbol varchar) with (value_format='integer', kafka_topic='myTopic');
```

This gives me an error... and looking at the documentation I see that value_format only supports delimited, json or avro. And, delimited didn't work for me.

Am I simply out of luck?

*** Update ***

It accepted:

```
create stream myStream(value INT) with (value_format='kafka', kafka_topic='myTopic');
```

But I don't get any data when I do:

```
select * from myStream;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was twofold:

1) I did need to use:

```
create stream myStream(value INT) with (value_format='kafka', kafka_topic='myTopic');
```

2) I needed to add Emit Changes;

```
select * from myStream Emit Changes;
```